# Pass a DataTime parameter to stored procedure and check a condition

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, parameter-passing

assumption:

I need to sync a '**PublicDB**' from a '**PrivateDB**' database. Where two parameters should pass to stored procedure, **server** name and a datetime type parameter.

**HistoryDate** is not primary key but use for updating.

Scenario:

If today is 8th and user do not select any **previous** date from dateTimePicker -UI- this stored procedure only will update records on 8th.

If today is 8th and user select 5th of month= targetdate in my SP, it should delete 'PublicDB' table from 4th then insert 5th, 6th and 8th again.

Problem:
server parameter works fine but for datatime parameter:

If Sp execute in sql server get this error:
*Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.*

if added to table Adapter it got this error:
*Generated SELECT statement*
   *Conversation failed when converting date / or time from character string.*
*To apply these settings to your query click finish*

### here is the sp:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spname] @Server SYSNAME,

@TDate NVARCHAR(50) --have tested: DateTime

AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @SQL1 NVARCHAR(2000);
    DECLARE @SQL2 NVARCHAR(2000);
    DECLARE @LastRecordDate DATETIME;
    DECLARE @Count INT;
    DECLARE @TargetDate DATETIME;

    SET @TargetDate = CONVERT(DATETIME, @TDate, 121);

    SET @Count = CONVERT(INT, 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM   [' + @Server + '].[PublicDB].[dbo].[TableName]

        WHERE HistoryDate >= [' + @TargetDate + '] ');

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @Count;

    IF @Count > 0 BEGIN

        SET @SQL1 = 'DELETE FROM [' + @Server + '].[PublicDB].[dbo].[TableName] 

WHERE HistoryDate >= [' + @TargetDate + '] 

  INSERT INTO [PublicDB].[dbo].[TableName]
    SELECT  TOP 5
       [HistoryDate]
      ,[columnName1]
      ,[columnName2]
      ,[columnName3]
      ,[columnName4]
      ,[columnName5]
      ,[columnName6]
      FROM PrivateDB.dbo.TableName
      WHERE HistoryDate >= [' + @TargetDate + '] 
  ';

        EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL1;

    END

    ELSE BEGIN

        SET @LastRecordDate = CONVERT(DATETIME, 'SELECT TOP 1 HistoryDate FROM [PublicDB].[dbo].[TableName] ORDER BY HistoryDate DESC', 121);

        -- has tested: cast('SELECT TOP 1 HistoryDate FROM [Public].[dbo].[TableName] ORDER BY HistoryDate DESC' as datetime)

        EXECUTE sp_executesql @LastRecordDate;

        SET @SQL2 = '

    INSERT INTO [' + @Server + '].[PublicDB].[dbo].[TableName]
      SELECT  TOP 5 
       [HistoryDate]
      ,[columnName1]
      ,[columnName2]
      ,[columnName3]
      ,[columnName4]
      ,[columnName5]
      ,[columnName6]
      FROM PrivateDB.dbo.TableName
      WHERE HistoryDate > [' + @LastRecordDate + ']

  ';

        EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL2;

    END


END
```

Answer (score 0):

I think these lines could be the problem

```
SET @Count = CONVERT(INT, 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM   [' + @Server + '].[PublicDB].[dbo].[TableName]
             WHERE HistoryDate >= [' + @TargetDate + '] ');
```

You are asking to convert a string / datetime to an int

I guess that you are trying to get a count from the select statement, one way would be something like the following (not tested!)

```
CREATE TABLE #t_count(no int) 
DECLARE @sqlcount varchar(1000)
DECLARE @count int
SET @sqlcount = 'INSERT into #t_count SELECT COUNT(*) 
            FROM   [' + @Server + '].[PublicDB].[dbo].[TableName]
            WHERE HistoryDate >=''' + convert(varchar(30),@TargetDate,120) + ''''
EXEC( @sqlcount )
SELECT @count = no FROM #t_count
```

example [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/24150/5)

**EDIT**

I see you updated your answer a little http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/14528

but if you read the answer above, you will see that it

creates a temp table

```
CREATE TABLE #t_count(no int)
```

builds an sql string to insert the count into the temp table

```
SET @sqlcount = 'INSERT into #t_count SELECT COUNT(*) 
                FROM   [' + @Server + '].[PublicDB].[dbo].[TableName]
                WHERE HistoryDate >=''' + convert(varchar(30),@TargetDate,120) + ''''
EXEC( @sqlcount )
```

gets the count value from the table

```
SELECT @count = no FROM #t_count
```

Your edit does not do this!

Also you are enclosing literal values in [] for some reason these need removed

good

```
where historydate = '2012-12-12 12:12'
```

bad

```
where historydate = [2012-12-12 12:12]
```

Comment: ps. Historydate column format likes this: 2008-09-25 00:00:00.000

Comment: I need to count if there is any new insertion of record after 7th day or not. If yes I should Insert records from PrivateDB to PublicDB for day 8th

Comment: I don have permission to add any column or table to PublicDB or PrivateDB. What I tried to get from this @count: assume publicdb has updated on 5th, but user made mistake and has corrected sth on 2nd of month. Therefore I need to delete all records on 2nd onwards then insert again 2nd , 3rd, 4th and 5th.

Comment: Also I don have permission to add a Flag, Modifieddate column on PrivateDB. It is funny but this is what they want.

Comment: I have updated the answer I made a couple of mistakes! - and provided a sqlfiddle snippet that should demonstrate one way to get the count.

Comment: Thanks for that now I got this Implicit conversion from data type datetime to int is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Comment: ah yes - you will note in the fiddle I passed a varchar for the date - will update the answer (but of course you may have jsut been able to pass in @ TDate instead of using @ TargetDate

Comment: But both Tdate and TargetDate are needed. Tdate az a parameter to pass to sp and @TargetDate to hold it. Still doesnt work

Comment: did you look at the sqlfiddle? Can you tell me what it is doing wrong ?

Comment: yes have seen that. actually I need to add this SP to a tableadpter. when added still get this error comes : conversation failed when converting... I need to use both TDate and TargetDate cause when I write TDate straight in WHERE clues it says: need CONVERT function

Comment: please add your amended sp to the question then

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/14528                                 thanks 100times

Comment: you have not made any changes - so you would get the same error!

Comment: I ve changed @count according to your suggestion. previously it was Convert(INT,'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [PublicDB].[dbo].[Tblname]
  WHERE HistoryDate >= [' + @ TargetDate + '] ');

Comment: USE [PrivateDB]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPname] 

  @ TDate datetime,
  @S erverName sysname

AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @ SQL1 nvarchar(2000);
DECLARE @ SQL2 nvarchar(2000);
DECLARE @ SQL3 nvarchar(2000);
DECLARE @ SQL4 nvarchar(2000);

DECLARE @ Count INT;

Comment: Select @ SQL1 = 'Select @ countNum=COUNT(*) from PrivateDB.dbo.TableName1 where ColumnName1 >= ''' + Convert(varchar,@ TDate) +'''';
EXEC sp_executesql @ SQL1, N' @ countNum INT OUTPUT', @ Count OUTPUT;
IF @Count > 0 
  Begin

   Set @ SQL2 = 'DELETE FROM ['+ @ ServerName +'].[PublicDB].[dbo].[TableName1]
    WHERE ColumnName1 >= ''' + Convert(varchar,@ TDate)  +'''
   INSERT INTO ['+ @ ServerName +'].[PublicDB].[dbo].[TableName1]
   SELECT   
     [ColumnName1]
    FROM PrivateDB.dbo.TableName1
    WHERE ColumnName1 >= ''' + Convert(varchar,@ TDate)  +'''
   ';

Comment: EXECUTE sp_executesql @ SQL2; 
   END

Else
 
 BEGIN
  DECLARE @ LastRecordDate DATETIME;

  SeLect @ SQL3 = 'SELECT TOP 1  @ topRec=ColumnName1 FROM  ['+ @ ServerName +'].[PublicDB].[dbo].[TableName1] ORDER BY ColumnName1 DESC';
  EXEC sp_executesql @ SQL3, N' @ topRec DATETIME OUTPUT', @ LastRecordDate OUTPUT;

Comment: Set @ SQL4 = '
  INSERT INTO ['+ @ ServerName +'].[PublicDB].[dbo].[TableName1]
   SELECT  
     [ColumnName1]
   FROM PrivateDB.dbo.TableName1
   WHERE ColumnName1 > ''' + Convert(varchar, @ LastRecordDate)  +'''
  ';
  EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL4;
 END